# Unlist multiple csv Files

Tags: r, csv

How can I unlist and rbind the csv files?

I had many csv files in a directory. They all have two columns and unequal number of rows. I made a list using

```
list.files(pattern=".csv$") # use the pattern argument to define a common pattern  for import files with regex. Here: .csv

list.filenames<-list.files(pattern=".csv$")

list.data<-list()

for (i in 1:length(list.filenames))
{
  list.data[[i]]<-read.csv(list.filenames[i])
}


names(list.data)<-list.filenames
```

The data look as follows:

```
$`xxx-xxx.csv`
    PositionX    Value
1           2 -107.068
2           6  -35.074
...
$`xxx1-xxx1.csv`
    PositionX   Value
1           2  -9.230
2           6  -9.230
...
```

There are thousands of csv files in the format mentioned above. I just would like to rbind them together and, without the header. For example I want to have:

> ```
> PositionX    Value
> 1           2 -107.068
> 2           6  -35.074
> 3           2  -9.230
> 4           6  -9.230
> ```

I have already tried  the following solutions:

```
big.list.of.data.frames <- lapply(list.data, function(x){
+     read.table(x, skip = 3, header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
+ })
```

I get the following:

```
 Error in read.table(x, header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE) : 
  'file' must be a character string or connection
```

I have also tried

```
myMergedData <- do.call(rbind,list.data)
```

I get the error:

```
Error in rbind(deparse.level, ...) : 
  numbers of columns of arguments do not match
```

I've made sure all my csv files have 2 columns.

Comment: `do.call(rbind,list.data)`

Comment: Already tried, I get 'Error in rbind(deparse.level, ...) : 
  numbers of columns of arguments do not match'

Comment: Then you don't have the same number of columns for all elements of the list. Check `str(list.data)` to make sure that all elements have only two columns.

Comment: Output is truncated, but all show 2 variables.

Comment: To get the full `str`: `str(list.data), list.len = length(list.data)))`

Comment: Position int and value num and all obs have 2 variables. And doing cbind gives `Error in data.frame(..., check.names = FALSE) ` where as r bind gives a different error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a list of read csv files:

```
list.data <- Map(read.csv, list.files(pattern=".csv$"))
```

Check if they all have two columns:

```
all(sapply(list.data, ncol)==2)
```

If this is not `TRUE` then investigate which of the files had more or less than 2 columns:

```
which(sapply(list.data, ncol)!=2)
```

Otherwise combine as suggested in the comments:

```
do.call(rbind, list.data)
```

Comment: I get `Error in match.names(clabs, names(xi)) : 
  names do not match previous names`

Comment: This means that your files have different headers (variable names).

Do you get the second line (with `all(`) to return `TRUE` ?

Comment: Yes I get all(sapply(list.data, ncol)==2)
[1] TRUE
> 
> which(sapply(list.data, ncol)!=2)
named integer(0)

Comment: Then your files have different variables names for those two columns. Or so it seems. If you are not afraid to ignore that then you can try this: `list.data <- Map(setNames, list.data, list(names(list.data[[1]])))` before running the last line.

Comment: I tried I still got the same error

Comment: It would help if you provided a few examples of how the first few lines of your files look like. Otherwise it's a bit hard to help in the blind.